# Tag badge progress bar not filled in properly

Tags: bug, design, tag-badges, badge-progress

The green bar demonstrating the progress toward a tag badge appears to be not filled in properly. It is definitely there on the answer bar, but the score bar is not perfect either.

Reproduced on Safari 9.1.1 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.

[image: Tag badge progress bar bug]

Comment: I think this happens whenever the bar is full, since I can repro on Firefox 47.0.1 on Windows but for score bar (which is full in my case).